# Are there any bi-bidirectionally indistinguishable Asymmetric Encryption Algorithms

Tags: public-key, algorithm-design

I have been using Asymmetric Encryption for a while, and I have come across an interesting concept, and it would be cool if it could be done.

Are there any Asymmetric Encryption Algorithms where the Encryption Key and the Decryption Key cannot be deciphered from one another?

Comment: Yes. $\:$ Generate two standard key key-pairs, and have Encryption Key and the Decryption Key be the pairs with an encryption key for one of the standard key-pairs and the decryption key for the other standard key pair.

Comment: Sounds interesting, how would that work?

Comment: One would Encrypt with the encryption key in the public key, and Decrypt with the decryption key in the private key. $\:$

Comment: But with the Public Key implementations I've worked with (RSA), you can calculate the Decryption Key from the Encryption Key

Comment: That ... would require calculating the (lower case) decryption key from the encryption key. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: opposite of that. according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696472/given-a-private-key-is-it-possible-to-derive-its-public-key, it's trivial to get the public from private, but I am trying to find a crypto system that has the public key which is unfeasible to calculate from the private key

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9503/discussion-between-ricky-demer-and-cgoddard)

Comment: Most IBE schemes are close. The public key is some publicly available information like your email address. To get the private key, the owner of the email address must prove to the Private Key Generator (PKG) that it owns the email address. Given the private key, the user cannot generate the public key (though it is public so everyone knows it).